# What's the different between "cargo build" and "cargo -- build"?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I got a problem by using this command `cargo -- build --features ffi`, and the built library does not contain symbols I want.

I debugged a whole day and finally found that `cargo build --features ffi` (no `--` before `build`) will work.

I searched for a while and didn't find what is the usage of a single `--`, so any help on when it is used and what's the different with or without this `--`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for helping, it seems that the answer does not solve my confusion, if cargo follow the same convention of BASH, the two command should make no difference...

Comment: Cargo does follow the same convention as bash, meaning that in `cargo -- build --features ffi`, the `--features` argument is not parsed, and therefore is ignored since `cargo build` ignores extra positional arguments.

Comment: @psionic12 I submitted pull request, this is obviously cargo bug https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/9561

Comment: @Inline that is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sergio already point out, the double dash (`--`) is commonly indicates the end of options argument after which only positional arguments may follow (also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382) for more details).

In this particular case, the double dash between `cargo` and `build` seems quite buggy as it behaviors inconsistently:

```sh
# Intended behavior, `--features ffi` is an option
cargo build --features ffi --
# Fails because no positional arguments are expected
cargo build -- --features ffi
# Silently ignores the positional `--features ffi`
cargo -- build --features ffi
```

However, thanks to @Inline's [bug fix](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/9561), we should expect this pit-fall to become an issue of the past.